# Power series expansion for $\sin(2x)\cos(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

So my objective is to find the power series expansion of

> $$\sin(2x)\cos(x)$$

This is what I know so far, I just need a little help find the series:

First of all, we know that ${\sin(2x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}}$ and that ${\cos(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}}$.

My question is when I'm trying to find the series expansion of two functions, both with known series, that multiply each other, do we simply add or multiply the series expansion of each function.

Comment: What about combining the power series of $\sin(x)$ and $\sin(3x)$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks for the tip, I wasn't aware of that method I'm going to go read up on it now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [trigonometric sum-product relations](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/trigonometry/trigonometric-identities/product-sum-and-sum-product-identities) to get something that just involves a difference of two sines:

$\sin(2x)\cos(x)=(1/2)(\sin(3x)+\sin(x))$